# Is it possible to download files from Subversion through a HTML Link?

Tags: html, svn, confluence, wiktionary

I want to publish some files from Subversion in a local Wiktionary (Confluence).
How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here :http://geekswithblogs.net/flanakin/articles/CompareSubversionWebTools.aspx

Something like `mod_dav_svn` should help you do what you want.